# This is regarding Static routes

Tags: networking, routing

Hi everyone I am new to this site. I have a situation at my office please guide me if any know about this

I have two connections

One is for Internet which gives ip address Dynamically
and the other one is for accessing my Application on a  remote machine

Ip address for this connection is

IP: 192.168.51.98
Subnet:255.255.255.240
Gateway:192.168.51.97

No DNS servers required for this connection

I need to type 202.54.149.115/gdms in IE to open my application

now the issue is I am not able to access internet and My application at the same time.

someone told me that this is possible by static route

Hardware available with me are

netgear wireless router 
netgear Dual Wan Router

Please guide me as i am in very bad situation

Thank you all of for your responce
I realised that I need to be more specific about my problem

I have computer with two connections
One is internet and one is for connecting to my database

Internet connection Dynamically gives Ip address
I connected this internet connection to my Wan Port of Wireless router
This Wireless routers dynamicall assisgs Ip address to my computer
I dont any issue with this router and connection

Coming to the other side 
Another connection for accessing my database is static IP
ISP gave me

IP address range given to my Lan : 192.168.51.98 to 112
Subnet Mask:255.255.255.240
Gateway :192.168.51.97
No DNS required for this connection

I need to type 202.54.149.115/gdms in IE to access my database

Please guide me to add a static routes so that I can access internet and my database simultaneously

Comment: You need more details, What do you mean by "I have two connections" ?  Where do you configure 192.168.51.98 ? (on your pc ? on the router ?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your text that:

- Both connections come into your PC and not the router.
- You are using IE, so you are using Windows.

Add a static persistent route to always reach your "application IP" through the second connection.

```
route -p add 202.54.149.115 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.51.97
```

Arguably you should also remove the default route on the second connection.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add a static route to the Netgear?

If so, you'd add a static route to 202.54.149.115 via 192.168.51.97

```
ip route 202.54.149.115 255.255.255.255 192.168.51.97
```

Something along those lines. I'm not familiar with the Netgear interface so can't give any exact syntax

I have assumed that 192.168.51.98 is your workstation you're using to access the application and 192.168.51.97 is your Netgear device

Comment: No it did not worked

Comment: What is doing the routing for your network?

It sounds like your workstation is making the decisions about which interface to send traffic down? If that is the case, you'll need to alter your routing table on your wokstation

Comment: Netgear router is routing 

Internet connection is connected to wan port of router
and another connection for accessing my data base is connected to lan port of my router

I am bale to get IP from my router and I am able to access internet but not my database

If I need to access my Database I am changing my Ip address of my computer to 192.168.51.98 255.255.255.240 192.168.51.97 
Please guide me

Comment: According to what you've posted, 192.168.51.98 and 192.168.51.97 are on different networks? Can you show a routing table from your Netgear device? Does it know about both networks?

Does the Netgear know about the network your database server is on?

Could you provide a topology diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Please could you clarify: do you have two NICs in you computer?

The correct way to handle this would be to have a single gateway for all your connections and let your gateway do the routing. You would only need a static route configured on your machine if you wanted the connection routed via somewhere other than your gateway, although even this is not advisable.

Ask whoever is responsible for your router to configure the static routes required on there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're asking for here, and I can't really walk you through reconfiguring your netgear device since I don't know much about them.

The common solution to this is to put a static route into your border device that says 'for traffic to this subnet, go to this gateway, for that subnet, use this other gateway, and for everything else, use this third gateway'.

Things that do IP networking chose the gateway that has the largest (most specific) netmask that matches the target IP address.

You can also put a static route on your specific system.  Again, this is OS specific, but there [this](http://www.itsyourip.com/networking/howto-add-persistent-static-routes-in-windows/) web page describes how to do it with windows.

Lastly, I'm not really sure what the topology of your network is, but you have to put the static route on the furthest device from your system which can see both networks, and this may well be your specific computer (if you've got two nics on your computer), but it may also be the netgear device.